# How can I compare to a JavaScript variable in an EL expression?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl, el

In `.jsp` file:

```
<script>
    String id = "S"; 
</script>
    
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${detail.status==id}">
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: That's a JS string. JSP is evaluated on the *server* side. If you want to do things based on JS then it needs to be done on the *client* side.

Comment: can i compare on .jsp?
i use <% String id = "S"%>
but still error

Comment: Values in JSP expressions have to be in one of the servlet scopes.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript and Java code run on different computers. You can't use both at the same time.

If you define a variable on the server to any other scope in jsp

```
request.setAttribute("id", "S");
```

then you can use

```
<script>
    String id = ${id}; 
</script>
```